# Importing conflicting jquery libraries in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems importing the jquery library at the end of the body. With this file, the autocomplete stops working. I can remove it but it's required from my bootstrap template.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var availableTags = [
                    "ActionScript",
                    "AppleScript",
                    "Asp",
                    "BASIC",
                    "C",
                    "C++",
                    "Clojure",
                    "COBOL",
                    "ColdFusion",
                    "Erlang"
                ];
                $("#autocomplete_jquery1").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input name="research" id="autocomplete_jquery1"/>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I think that there is a conflict between the jquery's imports. What do you think about? Thanks

Comment: Why import jQuery more than once?

Comment: Because I'm not sure they are precisely the same file

Comment: Please post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Separate your code into html, css and javascript. Delete the java code or at least add the java tag.

Comment: The examples from jquery place the import in the head while bootstrap template place the import at the end of the body

Comment: [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)? However, you should really do some research into what exactly you need to import and where. Typically, `script` tags go at the end of the body.

Comment: I've post a simplified version of the code. The two files are both v1.12.4

Comment: But if i remove the import at the end of the body it work fine (the autocomplete) but if i remove the import in the head the autocomplete doesn't work

Comment: When you import a new jQuery at the end of the page, anything that was done to modify that library, such as previously included plugins, would not exist on the new instance of jQuery.  So just choose one, top or bottom, and whatever you choose make sure your plugins are included after it and your logic that uses that library also proceeds it.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello -- that makes very little sense. Pick the version of jQuery you want and use it.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello because you must load it before any code that depends on it like plugins or your code. Order is important

Comment: Thanks, I only left the import in the head and now all work correctly